# Understanding the output of last reboot shutdown

Tags: linux, shutdown, reboot, last

When I use the command `last -x reboot shutdown` I get an output like this:

```
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-279.14.1. Tue Jul 18 22:03 - 03:20  (05:17) 
shutdown system down  2.6.32-279.14.1. Tue Jul 18 22:02 - 22:03  (00:00) 
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-279.14.1. Tue Jul 18 17:10 - 22:02  (04:52) 
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-279.14.1. Tue Jul 18 17:08 - 22:02  (04:54) 
shutdown system down  2.6.32-279.14.1. Tue Jul 18 17:08 - 17:08  (00:00)
```

I cannot understand what these entries mean; for example, did a `shutdown` took place at `17:08` followed by a `reboot` at `17:08` which lasted `04:54`? If so, what did happen at `17:10-22:02`?

**I want to understand exactly what all the time stamps mean (including the difference in the brackets)**. I tried `man last` and searching online but could not find an explanation. If someone could provide an explanation of the 5 lines above that would be very helpful.

Comment: This is a good & reasonable question given the current state of the `last` command, and its documentation `man last`. But IMHO, this question should not need to be asked. As I read it, `last` does not adhere to the [*Unix philosophy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy). I suppose part of this applies to the vagaries of `wtmp` construction, but I don't understand why this is the only tool available to determine when a system has been re-booted or shut down.

Answer (score 1):

`reboot   system boot  2.6.32-279.14.1. Tue Jul 18 17:08 - 22:02  (04:54)`

- `04:54` is system uptime.
- `17:08` is a system start time (1st boot time)
- `22:02` is systems next start time ( 2nd boot time)

Which means you have restarted system on 17:08 and 22:02. The time inside the braces indicates the uptime of the system which is 4hrs and 54min.